# ItemUpdating does not call on DetailsView using EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have a details view bound to an entity data source and am trying to use it to update some things. But the ItemUpdating event never fires when I press the Update button.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" DataKeyNames="Id" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" OnDataBound="DetailsView_DataBound" 
    DataSourceID="eds2"  BorderWidth="0" OnModeChanging="OnModeChanging" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnItemUpdated="DetailsView_OnItemUpdated"  OnItemUpdating="DetailsView_OnItemUpdating"
    EmptyDataText="N/A" 
    CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="7" GridLines="None" CssClass="Center">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name: "  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessCode" HeaderText="Access Code: "  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password: "  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MaxVoters" HeaderText="Max Voters: "  />                        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created" HeaderText="Created: " ReadOnly="true"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Updated" HeaderText="Updated: " ReadOnly="true"  />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

And the EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="eds2" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=BallotOnlineEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="EntitiesOne" EntitySetName="Accounts"  OnInserting="eds1_Inserting" OnUpdating="eds1_Updating" OnDeleting="eds1_Deleting"
    EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" 
    EnableUpdate="True">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="AccessCode" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

During the OnModeChange I set the where property of the Datasource so it queries for the right item, this was the only way I could get it to work, but I dont think that is a problem.

```
protected void OnModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    eds2.Where = string.Format("it.AccessCode = '{0}'",accountIDPlaceholder.Text );

    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}

protected void DetailsView_OnItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Stuff 
}
```

Any ideas why my event is not firing? The reason I want it to fire is that it does not seem to update the entities at all when I click update.

Thanks,

Ty Rozak

Comment: Are you canceling the update in the `eds1_Updating` handler (by setting `e.Cancel = true;`)?

Answer (score 1):

On your detailsview set

```
    CausesValidation="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `EnableViewState` on the page is not set to false.